# Where would I put the index.html file in a cloud server hosting environment?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting, cloud-hosting

I signed up for a cloud server hosting account since it supports Rails on GoDaddy.  I connected to the IP address through FTP using FileZilla.  The remote site directory has a folder with my username.  I put in an index.html file just to see if it would work, but when I navigate to the IP Address I get a "This site can't be reached error".  Where is the index file supposed to go?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for windows, you will have a folder named “wwwroot” to upload your content and in linux you will find public_html directory to upload your content.

Also, if you are on shared hosting, you will not be able to access your page using IP address since it will be allocated to default site with port 80.

So, kindly make sure that you have uploaded your page in correct directory and check if your site has binding with IP address and port 80 (Without host header value)

Answer (score 1):

***>>I connected to the IP address through FTP using FileZilla. The remote site directory has a folder with my username.***

Your host might be using cPanel server which has a directory structure like,

```
home/cPanel-username/public_html
```

Here "cPanel-username" is a directory with your domain name (first 8 letters).

***>>I put in an index.html file just to see if it would work.***

To make your website live, you'll need to upload your website files (including index page) in the directory "public_html".

```
home/cPanel-username/public_html
```

***>>when I navigate to the IP Address I get a "This site can't be reached error". Where is the index file supposed to go?***

Most probably, you have not set the GoDaddy nameservers at domain registrar panel. If not, you may access your website via temporary URL as follows.

```
http://server-IP-address/~cpanel-username
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter which cloud server hosting environment you are on, whether it is Alibaba Cloud or any other, the file will be uploaded in directory which is specified in the ftp configuration file. However, if you are using a web server then you need to check the Document root in the configuration file of the web server